# Obtaining JWT token from Azure AD using Python

Tags: azure, api, rest, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am working on an application that needs to obtain a bearer token form Azure AD. Right now I have everything set in Azure and I can generate/obtain the token using Postman (see picture)

[image: Obtaining Token in Postman is Working]

However, and this is my struggle, I am having problems obtaining the token programmatically using Python. The code below is what I have tried, with some variations of what to iinclude as fields in the request_payload, without any luck

```
import json
import requests

#TOKEN_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token"
TOKEN_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/41ff26dc-250f/oauth2/token?resource=https://graph.windows.net"
RESOURCE_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/41ff26dc-739be8610c21/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net"
def authenticate():
    request_payload = {
                        "callback_url" : "https://localhost",
                        "auth_url" : "https://login.microsoftonline.com/41ff26dc-250fc21/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net",
                        "access_token_url" : "https://login.microsoftonline.com/41ff26dc-739be8610c21/oauth2/token?resource=https://graph.windows.net",
                        "username": MY USER NAME,
                        "password": MY PASSWORD,
                        "resource": RESOURCE_URL,
                        "grant_type": "Authorization_Code",
                        "client_id": 'e0d00a8e-b799-4285-be3f-eb5822aaa86e',
                        "client_secret": '-n24Y2is~p5Jk7~6kYcp4~q2lrmnRCXoW_'}

    response = requests.post(url=TOKEN_URL, data=request_payload).json()
    
    print(response)

    bearer_token = response["access_token"]
    
    print(bearer_token)
    
    return bearer_token

print(authenticate())
```

This is the error I get when I fill in my credentials (MY USER NAME and MY PASSWORD) appropriately

```
{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'code'.\r\nTrace ID: d84b06a7-1c45-4657-bb3f-085248de5d01\r\nCorrelation ID: e431a09a-07dc-4c12-bf19-3b8ff7e7c358\r\nTimestamp: 2020-06-25 21:55:25Z", 'error_codes': [900144], 'timestamp': '2020-06-25 21:55:25Z', 'trace_id': 'd84b06a7-1c45-4657-bb3f-085248de5d01', 'correlation_id': 'e431a09a-07dc-4c12-bf19-3b8ff7e7c358', 'error_uri': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144'}
```

Any thoughts, suggestions or leads are very much appreciated. Like I said before, I am not sure what fields should I put in the payload, I am not even sure what are all possible fields to try there either.

Comment: Please let us know which authentication library you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this document for [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

you need to send below

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state=12345
```

please refer to this [python sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-webapp#more-information)